# How to show or hide fields on a GSP based on a selection in a combo-box

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class

I'm still new to grails, so I'm really sorry for asking something like this.

I have a domain that could be divided in 3 types, so I'd like to create a combo-box and depending on which selection the user made, it will show some fields and hide others. How can I achieve this?

Thanks again and sorry for this dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually something that is commonly done with JavaScript. You could attach an 'on change' event handler to your combo-box that would show/hide the appropriate elements as needed. 
In case you're not familiar with how to do this with Javascript, I'd recommend you take a look at jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I thought maybe there was a way to do it without Javascript.
Thanks for your prompt answer Shawn!

Comment: You can do this without JavaScript but that would require (arguably) more work because you would need to submit the form to the server, and you would place data in the request so that when the view is (re)rendered you could look at this data and do some if/else logic to show/hide elements on the page.  I prefer the client side approach assuming the logic is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Gregg, let me know when you visit Buenos Aires, to buy you a beer!
Cheers!